# Does the Split container control automatically resize the form?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms

Currently i am using a split container control from windows forms and a button which hides / shows the panel1 or panel2 of the split container when it is cliked.  The panel1 and panel2 are having different heights on the main form.

The problem is that the main form which holds the split container is not automatically resized once a panel gets hidden.

Is there an option on the split container that can also resize the height of the parent control ? Or some of you know how to handle this resize of the form once one of the panels of the spllit container gets hidden or shown ?

Comment: That's not the purpose of split containers.  Split containers do not change the form size, rather they allow you to share a forms size between two panels.  So if one of the panels uses none of the space provided, then the other panel will use all of the space provided.

Comment: So there are some other containers that can resize the form size once their content gets hidden or shown ?

Comment: Not that I have seen.  You could certainly write one though.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback ! It looks like that we are seting up a new start up :).

Comment: Sure there is; set the [AutoSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.autosize(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the container and Form to grow and shrink.

Comment: Several Container controls (Panel, FlowLayoutPanel, .....) have an AutoSize property and when you code their Resize event to adapt the Form.ClientSize you got what you want.. : `if (formsize smaller than panelsize) Form.ClientSize = panel.Size;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just place the Panels directly onto the Form and set their Location() property to the same value (make sure one isn't **nested** within the other).  Make one of them initially hidden and then toggle their visibility at run-time.  This can make designing the form a little tricky!

Set the AutoSize property of the Form to True, and the AutoSizeMode property to GrowAndShrink:

```
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Visible = !panel1.Visible;
        panel2.Visible = !panel2.Visible;
    }
```

My test form automatically changed sizes to accommodate the size of the currently visible panel.

Answer (score 0):

Just set scSplitContainer.Panel1Collapsed or scSplitContainer.Panel2Collapsed  = true